# char * str[] equivalent in C#

Tags: c#, c, dll, dllimport

I'm importing a function with the definition

```
 __declspec(dllexport) int __stdcall karacell_bridge( 
               int argumentCount, char *argContent[])
```

from a C DLL to a MS Visual Studio C# Project. How do I redefine the argument char *argContent[] in C#?

Can I use `MarshalAs`? Or is it right to define it as `public static extern int karacell_bridge( int argumentCount, string[] argContent)` in C#?

Comment: @zerkms Totally wrong. It is an array of C-strings. Note the `*` and the `[]`.

Comment: Isnt char*argContent[] an array of strings? char* in itself is an array.

Comment: @Shambavi yes, you are correct.  I think your C# guess will probably work. Try it!

Comment: @Shambavi: Nope, `char*` is a pointer to `char`, not an array.  `char *args[]` is an array of pointers to `char`.  Arrays are not pointers, and pointers are not arrays.

Comment: Now Im confused. Isnt char *args[] like char args[][]?

Comment: @EdS. in a function signature `char **` is equivalent to `char *arg[]`.

Comment: @EdS. They are equivalent. After all, an array in C is just a pointer to the first element. Shambavi, you are still correct.

Comment: @unkulunkulu: Sure, when passed to a function the array decays to a pointer.  That doesn't mean that a pointer is an array, though perhaps I was being overly pedantic

Comment: @JonathonReinhart: No, an array is not simply a "pointer to the first element."  Really, it's not.  How about this? `char a[10];` What is the type of `&a`?  Is it a pointer to pointer to char?  It would be if an array was a pointer, but of course, it's not; it's a pointer to array of char.  The differences are subtle but important.  It's honestly one of the least understood concepts in C

Comment: @JonathonReinhart: I did try it..somehow Im unable to see my DLL functioning, so I was worried if my C# function definition was wrong. So wanted to troubleshoot and confirm. Thanks! :)

Comment: `ref string[] argContent` ? an array of string by reference? depends on how it will be used and if the client expects the contents to be changed or not ...

Comment: Nope..the content isnt modified..So no need for ref I guess..

Comment: `char * arr[]` is basically an array of pointers to char. In C there are no `String Object` to use everything is just a pointer you need a string you save characters in continuous memory locations and end it with a null terminating character `\0` and you get a string.
Most probably he is using that to save strings.. if that is so you can make an Array of String Objects and you are all good to go.

Comment: Wouldn't this all just be a lot easier with `unsafe char* arr[]` ? Removes the fuss, and allows an almost direct port..

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
public unsafe static int karacell_bridge_wrapper(string[] input)
{
    char*[] argContent = new char*[input.Length];

    for(int i = 0; i < input.Length; i++)
    {
        char* str;
        fixed (char* cptr = input[i])
        {
            str = (char*)cptr;
        }
        argContent[i] = str;
    }

    return karacell_bridge(input.Length, argContent);
}
```

Remember to allow unsafe code in your C# project (rightclick -> properties -> build -> allow unsafe code)